# Integration test of Flink application

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to run an integration test of my flink application. My test code looks like this:

```
public class HttpsCsvIngestorTest extends AbstractTestBase {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpsCsvIngestorTest.class);

    @Test
    public void testHttpsCsvIngestion() throws Exception {

        Thread flinkJob = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String[] args = new String[] { "--configFile", "the/path/to/config.properties", "--secretKey",
                        "12345" };
                JobExecutionResult execResult = CsvProcessorFlinkDriver.runFlinkJob(args);
            }
        });

        flinkJob.start();
        LOG.info("Starting flink job");

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        String[] args2 = new String[] { "localhost", filename }; 
        FileUploadClient.main(args2);

        Thread.sleep(30000);
        assertTrue(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "C:/Desktop/Result.csv")
                .exists());
        System.out.println("Test completed. Going to shutdown flink job");
    }

}
```

Here I'm starting my flink application from a child thread, and uploading a file for processing from the main thread. The test runs fine, and I get the expected result file.
However, I get the following error at the end, when the application is being shut down:

```
2018-10-10 16:24:46,670 ERROR Source: JettyServerFileSource -> Map -> Process -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1) StreamTask StreamTask.java:477  - Error during disposal of stream operator.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend.dispose(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:174)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.dispose(AbstractStreamOperator.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.dispose(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.disposeAllOperators(StreamTask.java:473)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-10-10 16:24:46,670 ERROR Source: JettyServerFileSource -> Map -> Process -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1) StreamTask StreamTask.java:477  - Error during disposal of stream operator.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend.dispose(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:174)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.dispose(AbstractStreamOperator.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.dispose(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.disposeAllOperators(StreamTask.java:473)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-10-10 16:24:46,670 ERROR Source: JettyServerFileSource -> Map -> Process -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1) StreamTask StreamTask.java:477  - Error during disposal of stream operator.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend.dispose(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:174)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.dispose(AbstractStreamOperator.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.dispose(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.disposeAllOperators(StreamTask.java:473)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-10-10 16:24:46,671 ERROR Source: JettyServerFileSource -> Map -> Process -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1) StreamTask StreamTask.java:477  - Error during disposal of stream operator.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend.dispose(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:174)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.dispose(AbstractStreamOperator.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.dispose(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.disposeAllOperators(StreamTask.java:473)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-10-10 16:24:46,671 ERROR Source: JettyServerFileSource -> Map -> Process -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1) Task Task.java:843  - FATAL - exception in resource cleanup of task Source: JettyServerFileSource -> Map -> Process -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1) (12d3e0627e62ad44c57c45b720682e56).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Memory manager has been shut down.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.releaseAll(MemoryManager.java:470)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:824)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.awaitJobResult(JobClient.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.submitJobAndWait(JobClient.java:387)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.submitJobAndWait(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.submitJobAndWait(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:540)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.executeJobBlocking(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:714)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.TestStreamEnvironment.execute(TestStreamEnvironment.java:79)
    at mycode.CsvProcessorFlinkDriver.flinkJettyExecution(CsvProcessorFlinkDriver.java:132)
    at mycode.CsvProcessorFlinkDriver.runFlinkJob(CsvProcessorFlinkDriver.java:56)
    at com.demo.code.HttpsCsvIngestorTest$1.run(HttpsCsvIngestorTest.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/$a#-1711434410]] after [21474835000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.apache.flink.runtime.messages.JobClientMessages$SubmitJobAndWait".
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:604)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:338)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anonfun$close$1.apply(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anonfun$close$1.apply(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.close(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:140)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.stopScheduler(ActorSystem.scala:892)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$$anonfun$liftedTree2$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(ActorSystem.scala:826)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$$anonfun$liftedTree2$1$1.apply(ActorSystem.scala:826)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$$anonfun$liftedTree2$1$1.apply(ActorSystem.scala:826)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$$anon$3.run(ActorSystem.scala:842)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$TerminationCallbacks$$anonfun$addRec$1$1.applyOrElse(ActorSystem.scala:1021)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl$TerminationCallbacks$$anonfun$addRec$1$1.applyOrElse(ActorSystem.scala:1021)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:436)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:435)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Here CsvProcessorFlinkDriver.java:132 is the **executionResult = env.execute** line.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I also notice that if I start the flink application in the main thread of the test class(instead of from a child thread), execution does not progress to the lines starting from LOG.info("Starting flink job");

My flink version is 1.5.0. The test gives the same error even with flink-1.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

When a flink job ends, flink [unloads](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html) classes used by your code.

If something tries to use those classes after flink unloads them you usually end up with `ClassNotFound` exceptions. So you have to make sure no code touches those classes.

In your case you get a `NoSuchMethodError` on the class `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`. It seems like you use a different version of commons-io and JettyServerFileSource tries to [AutoClose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) some resource.

See if you have a dependency on `commons-io` that is different than version 2.4 (that's the version used by flink)

Comment: Thanks. Now the NoSuchMethodError has disappeared but I still see the "JobExecutionException: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager". error. Why would this be happening?